# How can I schedule a script to run routinely in Landscape?

Tags: scripts, landscape

I have created a script in Landscape to run `apt update` and `apt upgrade` on the rest of my Ubuntu servers.  The script works great but I can't see any options to have it scheduled to run daily or weekly or anything, I can only kick it off manually.  What's the procedure to get the script to run regularly?

Comment: Search `Cronjob`

Comment: Go with [systemd-timer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/Timers)

Comment: So this can't be done from within Landscape?  If I'm doing this from the shell, where do the scripts created in Landscape live?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Landscape is running on 18.04.6 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Landscape doesn't currently have recurring jobs. Scripts are one-time operations which happen either as soon as delivered to the client machine or at a specific future time.
You have a couple of options:

1. create a cron job or systemd timer on the client machine.
2. create a cron job to launch a script remotely from the `landscape-api` at regular intervals

There are also other tools which might do what you're trying to achieve.